# Reasons Congress would censure Trump and what that'd mean

Tags: united-states, president, congress, censure

I have seen and heard of multiple stories about Donald Trump accused of racism and because of what was going on in [Charlottesville](http://www.charlottesville.org/) and his words regarding it. So this brings me to wonder a few things:

- What would be some of the reasons Congress would want to "censure" Donald Trump?
- What exactly would "censuring" Trump mean for America, could it prevent something, etc.?

  - I saw they are forced to give up committee chairmanships (whatever that means)
  - I also saw it'd be an official statement of disapproval, etc.

The real question perhaps: Is this really all there is to this for what it means or is there more to this or could it be put into context so it's easy for a political dummy to understand what this means, does, etc.?

---

Related Articles:

- ["Pelosi endorses censure of Trump~"](http://www.politico.com/story/2017/08/18/pelosi-endorses-censure-of-trump-over-charlottesville-response-241784)
- ["3 representatives want to officially censure Trump after Charlottesville"](http://abcnews.go.com/Politics/representatives-officially-censure-trump-charlottesville/story?id=49281724)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A [Censure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censure_in_the_United_States) is a formal condemnation of the actions of an individual person. Both the House of Representatives and the Senate can make such a statement. They decide on doing so with a vote, just like with any other decision.

There are no direct consequences when the US President in censured by Congress. It is merely a symbolic gesture.

There were only three cases where US presidents were successfully censured, all of them over 150 years ago:

- Andrew Jackson in 1834 for withholding documents relating to his actions in defunding the Bank of the United States.
- John Tyler in 1842 for various reasons. Long story short: There was a motion to impeach him. When that impeachment failed, a Senate committee decided to at least censure him.
- James Polk in 1848 for inciting the Mexican–American war without Congress approval.

There were also some failed attempts at censuring the president which did not achieve the necessary majority:

- Abraham Lincoln in 1864 for violating the rule that members of congress must not hold an army commission.
- Bill Clinton in 1998 for the Lewinski scandal (the only example from recent history).

The thing about committee chairmanship is specific to the censure of a Congressmember by the Congress. In that case they automatically lose the chairmanship in any Congress committees they lead. But that's not relevant in the case of a censure of the President. The President is not a member of Congress and thus isn't even a member of any committees, let alone chairman. If you have questions about Congress committees, that would be a topic for a different question